# Permanently set a new resolution for an unrecognized monitor (Huion GT-190 tablet monitor over VGA)

Tags: display, display-resolution

So, I have a Huion GT-190 widescreen tablet monitor. On Windows, it works fine, with a native resolution of 1440×900. On my Ubuntu MATE installation, though, it runs with a generic VGA monitor driver and the reported resolutions are incorrect, with the resolution option in “Displays” showing only 1280×1024, 1024×768, 800×600, 640×480, and 720×400. That last one is the only resolution given that uses the entire screen area—everything else is pillarboxed on the sides, like a pre-HD TV show.

[Even the “Displays” control panel seems to think there’s something wrong here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjXvX.png), with weird graphical glitches (the “HAT 15"” screen on the left is the Huion GT-190) as though the program is competing with itself over whether the monitor is 4:3 or 16:9.

I found a way to fix this in-session:

```
~ $ cvt 1440 900
# 1440x900 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.30MA) hsync: 55.93 kHz; pclk: 106.50 MHz
Modeline "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync
~ $ xrandr --newmode "1440x900_60.00"  106.50  1440 1528 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -HSync +VSync
~ $ xrandr --addmode VGA-2 1440x900_60.00
~ $ xrandr --output VGA-2 --mode 1440x900_60.00
```

…however, this has some weird graphical side-effects with my two-monitor setup, indicating that the desktop environment isn’t clear on where one monitor ends and the other begins. Usually these are fixed by going into the “Displays” panel and explicitly setting where the two monitors are in relation to each other, but not always.

So, I want to make sure that X knows exactly to what resolution this monitor should be set, on startup—not after-the-fact like with xrandr (or a script running xrandr). I imagine, in this mercifully xorg.conf-less world of today, that I must have to tell X how to auto-configure this specific model of monitor when detected. How and where do I do this?

Here is the EDID information for the Huion monitor:

```
00000000: 00ff ffff ffff ff00 2034 9014 0000 0000  ........ 4......
00000010: 2a16 0103 6e1e 1778 ea40 949c 5752 9226  *...n..x.@..WR.&
00000020: 1c50 54ad cf10 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101  .PT.............
00000030: 0101 0101 0101 8129 a0d0 5184 2230 5098  .......)..Q."0P.
00000040: 3600 f8c2 2100 0020 0000 00fc 0043 4e44  6...!.. .....CND
00000050: 4c43 440a 2020 2020 2020 0000 00fd 003c  LCD.      .....<
00000060: 4b1e 5f16 000a 2020 2020 2020 0000 00ff  K._...      ....
00000070: 0030 3030 300a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a 0a0a 00d6  .0000...........
```

…it’s pretty opaque, I know. For what it’s worth, the model number (as mentioned) is GT-190, while the serial number is 69DA4SH00349.

Comment: I would try to make own EDID file, which will have the correct resolution settings. Then make Xorg read this file instead of EDID acquired from monitor. Maybe this can help http://www.analogway.com/en/products/software-and-tools/aw-edid-editor/

Comment: The correct location for setting up it seems to be `/etc/X11/Xsession.d`, where you can add only parts of config, which override defaults (custom EDID in your case). You should also be able to put custom modeline in that directory.